# With PyO3 how can I import a Python module once and then use it in multiple Rust threads?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

Using PyO3, from a long-running Rust application I want to be able to call some functions many times. Before that I need to import a few modules. How can I do the imports just once and then re-use the `PyModule`s from other threads that call the functions? Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
let x: PyResult<&PyModule> = Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let pm = py.import("time")?;  // Only do this once
    Ok(pm)
});
let my_module = x.unwrap();
let mut handles = vec![];
for i in 0..2 {
    let t = thread::spawn(|| {
        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            // Use my_module here
        });
    });
    handles.push(t);
}
for h in handles {
    h.join();
}
```

The above code will not compile due to lifetime errors. How should I change it, so that I can use that shared `my_module` instance across my app, in different threads?

Answer (score 3):

You need three things for this to work

- The return value of `import` is an `&'py PyModule`. The `'py` means you cant take that out of the `with_gil` scope. (The `for<'py>` [here](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/marker/struct.Python.html#method.with_gil) enforces that. Roughly, it says that `'py` might be　anything, for example as short as the call to `with_gil`.) You must [convert](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/types/struct.PyModule.html#impl-IntoPy%3CPy%3CPyModule%3E%3E-for-%26PyModule) it into a `Py<PyModule>`, which you're free to do with what you want.
- If you're planning on passing a reference to a thread (that is, a `&Py<PyModule>`), rust must know that the thread can't outlive the reference. Crucially, it must know that from the type/lifetime system, which isn't affected by `h.join()`. The solution is [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html). (You could also solve this by `clone`ing the `Py` in the loop before you spawn the thread.)
- Finally, you can remove that pesky `Py` wrapper with `.as_ref(py)` as long as you have another GIL.

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let x: PyResult<Py<PyModule>> = Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let pm = py.import("time")?; // Only do this once
        Ok(pm.into())
    });
    let my_module = x.unwrap();
    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for _ in 0..2 {
            s.spawn(|| {
                Python::with_gil(|py| {
                    my_module.as_ref(py);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I do hope you're doing something other than acquiring the GIL in your threads, otherwise spawning threads would be rather pointless.

Comment: You can `clone()` the `Py` and avoid scoped threads, if needed.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Thought [cloning](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html#method.clone_ref) required the GIL.